# Modified central binomial coefficients generating function

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I would like to find the ordinary generating function of the sequence $a_k = \binom{2n-2k}{n-k}$.

If
\begin{align}
A(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_kx^k,
\end{align}
then I find that
\begin{align}
A(x) &= \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{2n-2k}{n-k}x^k \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{2k}{k}x^{n-k} \\
&= x^n\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{2k}{k} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^k
\end{align}
but I am stuck here. My understanding is that you cannot extend the last finite sum into an infinite series, so I cannot use the generating function of $\binom{2k}{k}$.

I have also tried rewriting $A(x)$ as
\begin{align*}
A(x) &= [y^n]\left(1 + xy + (xy)^2 + \cdots\right)\left(\sum_{i \ge 0} \binom{2i}{i}y^i\right)\\
&= [y^n] \frac{1}{1-xy}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4y}}
\end{align*}
but I have no idea how to proceed from here.

Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the original problem, like I believe, is the computation of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}$, by convolution you only need $\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k}{k}x^k$, since $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=[x^n]\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{2k}{k}x^k\right)^2.$$

Comment: Hi Jack, sadly no, I am genuinely interested in the generating function of $\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}$.

Comment: I'm not hopeful for a nice answer. When I asked Mathematica for the generating function, it gave something involving the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$.

Answer (score 3):

We consider $a_{n,k}=\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}$ with $n,k\geq 0$ non-negative integers.

- *Horizontal GF:* First of all we note that
  \begin{align*}
  A_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_{n,k}x^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}x^k\qquad\qquad n\geq 0
  \end{align*}
  is a polynomial in $x$ and as such a perfect ordinary generating function, a so-called *horizontal* generating function. Since it is a polynomial having a finite number of terms $a_{n,k}x^k$ not equal to zero, we do not expect a representation via $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$ which is an infinite series.
- *Vertical GF:* On the other hand we can consider the *vertical* generating function for fixed $k\geq 0$:
  \begin{align*}
  B_k(y)&=\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_{n,k}y^n=\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}y^n\\
  &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}y^{n+k}\\
  &=\frac{y^k}{\sqrt{1-4y}}
  \end{align*}
- *Bivariate GF:* We have the *bivariate* generating function $G(x,y)$ with $A_n(x)$  and $B_k(y)$ as horizontal resp. vertical section:
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{G(x,y)}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_{n,k}x^ky^n\\
  &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}x^ky^n\\
  &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}x^ky^{n+k}\\
  &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(xy)^k\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}y^n\\
  &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-xy}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4y}}}
  \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Mathematica result that I mentioned in the comments, in case it's helpful.  It uses Gauss's hypergeometric series ${}_2F_1$ (for background, see the beginning of Gasper & Rahman's *Basic Hypergeometric Series*, Cambridge, 2004).

$$\sum_{=0}^ {2n-2k \choose n-k} ^ = {2n \choose n} \, {}_2F_1\!\left(1,-n;\frac{1}{2}-n;\frac{x}{4}\right)$$